# Хотел сделать миграции после создания модели user в приложение user и вот что

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Люди, попытался сделать миграции

```
python manage.py migrate 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
        main()
      File "manage.py", line 18, in main
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/home/ilya/Рабочий стол/REST/venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
   packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
      File "/home/ilya/Рабочий стол/REST/venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
   packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/home/ilya/Рабочий стол/REST/venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
   packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "/home/ilya/Рабочий стол/REST/venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
   packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/home/ilya/Рабочий стол/REST/venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
   packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
        res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ilya/Рабочий стол/REST/venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
   packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 95, in handle
        executor.loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
      File "/home/ilya/Рабочий стол/REST/venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
   packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 302, in check_consistent_history
        raise InconsistentMigrationHistory(
    django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial 
    is applied before its dependency user.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

Comment: исправьте вопрос, чтоб код мог читаться

Comment: удалите все файлы прошлых миграций и сделайте заново makemigrations и migrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**У кого такая же проблема - надо было просто удалить все миграции вручную!**
Спасибо  Captain Mountain

> удалите все файлы прошлых миграций и сделайте заново makemigrations и migrate – Captain Mountain